# how to setState for an array of fulfilled promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await

In my react app, I am retrieving some data from firebase , but when I try to store the items in my state it stores only the first item of the fulfilled promises ,

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  const [events ,setEvents] = React.useState([])
const fetchGames=async()=>{
    const DB =await db.collection('game').get()

    DB.docs.forEach(item=>{
      setEvents([...events,item.data()])
      console.log(item.data()); // Here shows all the items that stored in my firebase collection
     })
    }
    
    useEffect(()=>
    {
      fetchGames()
    }, [])
return(
<div>
{
     events.map((event)=>
        (
          <div>
            {event.home_color}
          </div>

        )
        )
    }
</div>
)
```

Eventually the events state will display only one item , unlike in the console log which displayed all the items , how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state is not `synchronous`. So updating state in a for loop **does not guarantee** every iteration you will get an updated state.

You can prepare the final object in the `forEach` & then update state once it has finished. Something like -

```
const fetchGames=async()=>{
    const DB =await db.collection('game').get()
    const eventsFromDb = [];
    DB.docs.forEach(item=>{
      // update eventsFromDb array here 
    })
    // set state here
    setEvents(eventsFromDb);
}
```

Comment: how can I possibly make this ?

Comment: Updated answer with pseudocode.

Comment: Can you please add more specific lines concerning the "update eventsFronDb array here" i didnt succeed implementing it

Comment: You can try `eventsFromDb.push(item.data())`. Not sure what did you try

Comment: ah okay thanks I made it , ` DB.docs.forEach((item,index)` is the way

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly calling `setEvents` in your forEach loop does not allow for the state to actually be updated because the React useState hook is not synchronous.

You could do something like this:

```js
setEvents([ ...events, ...DB.docs.map(item => item.data())])
```

Assuming the `data()` method isn't async - sorry I don't know Firebase.